# Adding custom attributes to django model field

Tags: django, django-models

Can I add some arbitrary attributes to django model field?

For example:

```
charField = models.CharField('char field', max_length=1024, aaaaa=true)
```

Can I add attribute aaaaa?

Is this doable?

Comment: What do you want this attribute to do exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check `CharField`

```
class CharField(Field):
    description = _("String (up to %(max_length)s)")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.validators.append(validators.MaxLengthValidator(self.max_length))
```

It accepts `**kwargs` but also calls `super` and inherited `__init__` (`Field` object) only accepts named parameters.

```
class Field(object):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, primary_key=False,
        max_length=None, unique=False, blank=False, null=False,
        db_index=False, rel=None, default=NOT_PROVIDED, editable=True,
        serialize=True, unique_for_date=None, unique_for_month=None,
        unique_for_year=None, choices=None, help_text='', db_column=None,
        db_tablespace=None, auto_created=False, validators=[],
        error_messages=None):
```

So you can not pass a custom argument.

You must [create a custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-custom-model-fields)

Answer (score 5):

You can assign it as attribute to field object itself:

```
charField = models.CharField('char field', max_length=1024)
charField.aaaaa = True
```

Or if you want one liner create a function e.g.:

```
def extra_attr(field, **kwargs):
  for k, v in kwargs.items():
    setattr(field, k, v)
  return field
```

and then use:

```
charField = extra_attr(models.CharField('char field', max_length=1024), aaaaa=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at /django/db/models/fields/**init**.py, you can see that such behavior is not intended as Field.**init** accepts only predefined arguments.

You are, of course, free to write your own custom fields (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
class SpecialCharField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.aaaaa=kwargs.pop('aaaaa',false)
        super(SpecialCharField,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class ModelXY(models.Model):
    charField = SpecialCharField('char field', max_length=1024, aaaaa=true)
```

Comment: You provably prefer to use `kwargs.pop('aaaaa')` instead of retrieving with `.get` and then creating a new kwargs object.

Answer (score 0):

You failed to mention what you want this attribute to *actually* do.

Generally speaking, if you're trying to customize the `CharField` behavior, and it's not something `CharField` provides out-of-the-box, you'll need to create your own `CustomCharField` that extends `models.CharField` and implements the behavior you're expecting from `aaaaaaa=True`.