# Adding Parameters to Existing Django Model Fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

> Note: there is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679057/adding-custom-attributes-to-django-model-field) on a similar problem, but this question is more detailed and the answer mentioned in the post above is not satisfactory (elaborated below)

I was trying to create a custom Django model field, where the new field will essentially be the same as a `CharField` but has an *additional boolean attribute* -- for now, just call it "public."

I have looked up [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679057/adding-custom-attributes-to-django-model-field), but I don't like the method described as it required me to construct a model from scratch. That solution is a hassle considering the number of functions I must implement to add a parameter, per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-a-field-subclass).

To clarify my objectives, I will like to declare this field as such:

```py
somefield = BoolCharField(public=True, max_length=100, blank=True)
# Note that public is NOT a default CharField attribute
```

The documentation stated that I can extend new fields from existing ones, but [the process](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#changing-a-custom-field-s-base-class) isn't elaborated. Can anyone please provide me with an **example** of how I should implement my field?

[This](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1002) is the source code of CharField in case anybody needs a reference.

**Update**

I had a look at overriding the default `__init__` method. Here's what the documentation suggests:

```py
from django.db import models

class HandField(models.Field):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 104
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, the docs didn't specify how exactly overriding works in this case (e.g. where should I throw in *an additional attribute* and what methods I must include), which made me post this question.

Again, as I have been stuck for quite some time, I'd prefer examples instead of concepts.

Comment: You can override the ***`__init__(...)`*** method, right?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu In the docs, it said that "The Field.__init__() method takes the following parameters:" with a list of arguments, and it doesn't seem like I can override the custom arguments -- I mean, if I overrode the entire method, there are no documentation to back this method up